# Parse Xml attributes via XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Good day!

I try to parse Xml document:

structure:

```
<root>
  <SelectedConfig name="configuration1"/>
    <config name="configuration1">
     <Column Id="0"  name="111"/>
  ...
 </root>
```

I try to parse it like this:

```
 XmlNode configNameNode = _doc.SelectSingleNode("//SelectedConfig");

        if (configNameNode != null)
        {
            string configName = configNameNode.Attributes["name"].Value; 

            var config = _doc.SelectNodes("//config");

            XmlNodeList columnNodes = _doc.SelectNodes("//config/Column");

            foreach (XmlNode node in columnNodes)
            {
                var id = node.Attributes["Id"].Value;
                var name = node.Attributes["name"].Value;

                Tuple<string, String> numberOfColumnToColumnName = new Tuple<string, string>(id, name);
                numberOfColumnToColumnNameTupleColl.Add(numberOfColumnToColumnName);

            }
        }
```

But, if i add:

```
<config name="configuration2">
```

I get N*2 nodes of //config/column.

How to select only one set of xml nodes- from configuration1 or 2?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `configNameNode.SelectNodes("//config");`

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple nodes "config", each with multiple child nodes "column".
Because all these nodes have the same name and only differ in their attributes, the function `XmlNodeList columnNodes = _doc.SelectNodes("//config/Column");` will collect all "column" nodes of all "config"s.
Solution 1: rename config nodes to config_xxx, e.g. config_configuration1. But I think that's not what you want.
Solution 2: `config = _doc.SelectNodes("//config");` already gets you a node list. Run a `for each cfgEntry in config` over the list, calling `cfgEntry.SelectNodes("column")` on each node. Then you will get only the column nodes of that single config node.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the selected configuration, you can try the following code.

```
string xPath = string.format("//config[@name='{0}']/Column", configName);
var config = _doc.SelectNodes(xPath);
```

Comment: I think the `[attrib=...]` should be behind "config" and not behind "column"...?